# CTk Entry widget get text not woring

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

When I use CTkEntry() and try to get the value from the entry field, an error occurs `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

any solutions?

I just need to get the value for the entry to perform certain calculations

Comment: With out a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to help. I suspect you used your geometry method on the same line.

Comment: Please share the code for us to check. Thanks.